# RSpec runs using rvm on Mac but fails on require on Linux

Tags: ruby, rspec, jenkins

I have a ruby project that I've been developing on my mac using ruby 1.9.3 through rvm.
I've spent most of my day today setting up a build server to run my tests as I check in changes to my repo. My server runs Ubuntu. I installed rvm and use 1.9.3 as well.

However now I get load errors when I try to run my rspec tests using

```
bundle exec rspec
```

this works on my Mac and I can't figure out why its not working on my Linux machine.

```
morten@Lux:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/getdone/workspace$ bundle exec rspec
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/getdone/workspace/spec/lib/commandExecutor_spec.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- CommandsExecutor (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/getdone/workspace/spec/lib/commandExecutor_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/morten/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load'
    from /home/morten/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/morten/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
    from /home/morten/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/morten/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/morten/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/morten/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

The require line just says

```
require 'CommandsExecutor'
```

and the commandsExector.rb is located in my lib directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X' file system is case-insensitive by default, while Linux file systems are usually case-sensitive. You say that the file is named `commandExecutor.rb`, so the correct way to require is

```
require 'commandExecutor'
```

PS: As a side note, it's a common-convention to not use upper-case letters in file names for Ruby (and most other programming languages), C# and Java being some prominent exclusions.

Comment: I have switched to the Mac 6 months ago, and ignored this case-insensivity of the FS.